# How to display a url in php which end part is stored in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, youtube

I'm trying to create a form in which a user inserts their youtube code into a field, which is then stored in mysql.

When the code is added to the end of this link  - //www.youtube.com/embed/[code here] - it displays the video.

How can I do it so that the link is permanently fixed in the php document and the end part is retrieved from mysql in a way that when the page is opened it displays the video correctly?

Very simple stuff when you know how to do it but I don't so I would appreciate if someone could tell me the way of doing this.

thanks!
Eugenie

Comment: Could you at-least show us what you have tried to do and what errors you are getting

Comment: Hi, was trying to get suggestions on what to try.  I've actually come up with the right script following lead from last answer but haven't got enough reputation to put just yet. I'll do it tomorrow. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To break apart the link and get the code for inserting:

```
$link = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/s0m3C0d3123";
$parts = explode("/", $link); // Split the URL into an array delimited by /
$code = $parts[count($parts)-1]; // Get the last value in the array 
// Insert $code into database
```

Print value from DB, assuming you already did a query for the code and it is stored in an array called $data

```
$link = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" . $data["code"];
echo $link;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this in my own projects. When someone pastes in the YouTube link, parse the video ID out and store that. Make sure you handle all existing link formats, YouTube has a few. Then when you go to display the video you can set up the embed tags any way you want, using the code you have in the database.

`exlode()` is your friend for parsing tokens out of URLs. Regex is painful to use unless you really need it.

I will assume you know enough to actually store and retrieve the YouTube ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `explode` like

```
$segments = explode('/', $MyUrl);
$cnt = count($segments);
echo $segments[$cnt-1];
```

Comment: I'm a bit of a dummy when it comes to all this. Unfortunately this is way out of my league. Looks like Chinese to me.  Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

i assume that yo need to store last part of the path.

```
<?php
$path = " //www.youtube.com/embed/filename.php";

//Show filename with file extension
echo basename($path) ."<br/>";

//Show filename without file extension
echo basename($path,".php");
?>
```

The output would be something like this:

filename.php

filename

Comment: The last part is stored in the db but how do I retrieve it so that it displays the video?

Answer (score 0):

Last answer put me on right track.   The following code displays it correctly:

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="------"; // Mysql username 
$password="-----"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="----"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="-------"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


$sql = "Select * from $tbl_name";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

echo "<div align='center'><iframe src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/" . $row['clip3'] . "\"     style=\"background: #fff;\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"300\" scrolling=\"auto\" width=\"480\"></iframe>     </div>";

}


?>
```